# CakePhP 1.3 multiple and or conditions in find

Tags: php, cakephp, conditional-statements

I'm trying to retrieve the latest images uploaded to my site but not when they're in a private gallery, event or if the user is deleted. I need to do these checks on a 0 or a null as well.

I've looked around and found a fair few ways of doing multiple and's and multiple or's but not together. It seems to look correct but doesn't work at all.

```
$conditions = array(
            'AND' => array(
                array(
                    'OR' => array(
                        'Event.private'     => null,
                        'Event.private'     => 0
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'OR' => array(
                        'Gallery.private'   => null,
                        'Gallery.private'   => 0
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'OR' => array(
                        'User.deleted'      => null,
                        'User.deleted'      => 0
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $images = $this->Image->find('all',array(
                        'order'=>array('Image.id'=>'desc'),
                        'limit'=>$limit,
                        'group'=>'Image.id',
                        'offset'=>$offset,
                        'conditions'=>$conditions)
                    );
```

Comment: "doesnt work at all"? any details? maybe you can post your sql query that cake generates and runs here.

Comment: Well it only loads 11 entries out of a few hundred possible entries. It also crashes the hell out of the javascript that renders out the images. I don't have access to the view so can only test it with debugging.

If i however add a condition to only get images from a private gallery, that part works. so the only part that seems to not be working is my and or tree, and as i cant find an example of the correct syntax the only thing I can think of being wrong is that somehow.

Comment: Allways switch on debug SQL for check query

Comment: Never use a key twice in an array (a key 'Event.private' would overwrite the first one in the same array!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OR statements should probably be also in an array.

Try following conditions:

```
$conditions = array(
    'AND' => array(
        array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('Event.private' => null),
                array('Event.private' => 0)
            )
        ),
        array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('Gallery.private' => null),
                array('Gallery.private' => 0)
            )
        ),
        array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('User.deleted' => null),
                array('User.deleted' => 0)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked a treat. I remember reading about having multiple or's and them needing to be in an array due to over writing each other. Never considered the same for multiple sections in an or :)